# Can one access the selected text from the command line with OSX?

Tags: mac, clipboard

On linux, there is the concept of the selection buffer. This normally contains the currently selected text.

The text in the selection buffer can be accessed with `xclip -o`.

Is there an analogous command for apple macs? I found `pbpaste`, but I could not work out how to have this access the *selection buffer* (or apple equivalent) rather than the clipboard.

## Possible approaches

- Install xclip with homebrew
- There does seem to be an analogue of [xclip's -selection option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) in the form of [the -pboard option](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html). But I can't really understand what the different paste boards mean.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure there’s no way to do this on macOS. Mac apps are not built on the X window system, so xclip won’t work with native Mac apps.

The `-pboard` option is not what you’re looking for either. These are special purpose pasteboards, not some app’s current selection buffer.